# Looking for docs about Android killing the process when runtime permission is revoked

Tags: android, android-permissions

When the user gives my Android app a runtime permission (e.g. BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) and it's running, and then the user goes to app settings and revokes this permission, the process is killed and restarted. It has been like this for years now, and this is fine by me.

However, I'm failing to find any official documentation about this. The closest I could find is this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting, but this specifically talks about 'one-time permissions', and even says `As with any permission, if the user revokes your app's one-time permission, your app's process terminates.`, i.e. it is assumed the reader knows the process terminates when permissions are revoked. But where is it documented?

Comment: Why do you assume it would be?  Not every behavior of an OS is documented in the official documentation.  For that matter, not every bit of documentation is up to date or correct.

Comment: I'm assuming that because this seems to be a Very Important Detail about the behavior of runtime permissions, as it leads to apps being killed. I have made wrong assumptions before, though, and you are right about docs, and Android docs specifically are often of dubious quality (IMHO). Are you implying this is not documented anywhere?

Comment: I'm implying it likely isn't.  That's the type of detail that tends to be mentioned in passing if at all-  it's a tiny corner case that you'll see once in a tens of thousands of real life runs (users don't really revoke permissions, that' something QA tests and users don't tend to do) and you can't do anything about anyway, it's not exactly important to API documentation.  And I'd say the Android docs are about on par with every other OS's docs I've ever read.  Nothing that big gets every decision documented, especially as many are implementation details rather than choices.

Comment: However it is a well understood behavior, so if you're questioning if you can rely on it I'd say yes.

Comment: In some sense, it's documented there, in the sentence you quoted.  I tried figuring out if I could reorganize that section to more affirmatively state it without making major structural changes to the page, but I don't know the inner workings of permissions (e.g., if the last sentence of the paragraph also applies to the non-one-time case) well enough to do it.  Is there a particular other page you'd expect to see it on?

Comment: @RyanM I was expecting to see it on this very page, which introduces runtime permissions and describes how they behave and what devs need to do. And to be quite honest, I would be totally happy with one sentence, pretty much the one I quoted, but that refers to the permissions in general (I believe the one I quoted is really only about one-time permissions).